# Error when trying to print html table to pdf

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to print a html table to pdf. The code to print the table in javascript looks like:

```
function createPDF(){
    var table = document.getElementById('mytable');

    var style = "<style>";
    style = style + "table {width: 100%;font: 17px Calibri;}";
    style = style + "table, th, td {border: solid 1px #DDD; border-collapse: collapse;";
    style = style + "padding: 2px 3px;text-align: center;}";
    style = style + "</style>";

    // CREATE A WINDOW OBJECT.
    var win = window.open('', '', 'height=700,width=700');

    win.document.write('<html><head>');
    win.document.write('<title>Profile</title>');   // <title> FOR PDF HEADER.
    win.document.write(style);          // ADD STYLE INSIDE THE HEAD TAG.
    win.document.write('</head>');
    win.document.write('<body>');
    win.document.write(table);         // THE TABLE CONTENTS INSIDE THE BODY TAG.
    win.document.write('</body></html>');

    win.document.close();   // CLOSE THE CURRENT WINDOW.

    win.print();    // PRINT THE CONTENTS.
}
```

The table if filled dynamically with javascript, don't know if that's important. Anyway whenever I try to print the html table I get [object HTML TableElement] in my pdf document. Does anybody know what the problem can be?

Comment: Or better `win.document.body.appendChild(table);`

Comment: To clarify, you're grabbing the table element, then writing it to the document. This will force cast the element to a string, and the browser uses the class name for that, in square brackets, not the HTML the element contains.

Comment: @mousetail That is hard when they use document.write

Comment: You can do it at the end, though you have to be careful with the order indeed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You need to get the HTML from the table - you only get the object - instead do
   `var table = document.getElementById('mytable').outerHTML`
   OR
   append the table object to the win.document but in any case
2. You really should only write once

```js
function createPDF(){
    const table = document.getElementById('mytable').outerHTML;

    const style = `<style>
     table {width: 100%;font: 17px Calibri;} 
     table, th, td {border: solid 1px #DDD; border-collapse: collapse; 
     padding: 2px 3px;text-align: center;} 
     </style>`;

    // CREATE A WINDOW OBJECT.
    const win = window.open('', '', 'height=700,width=700');
    const html = `<title>Profile</title>
    ${style}
    ${table}`;
    
    win.document.write(html);
    win.document.close();   
    win.print();    
}
```

Using objects (NOT tested):

```js
function createPDF(){
    const table = document.getElementById('mytable');

    const style = document.createElement("style");
    style.textContent = `table {width: 100%;font: 17px Calibri;} 
     table, th, td {border: solid 1px #DDD; border-collapse: collapse; 
     padding: 2px 3px;text-align: center;}`
     

    // CREATE A WINDOW OBJECT.
    const win = window.open('', '', 'height=700,width=700');
    const doc = win.document;
    const title = document.createElement("title");
    title.textContent = "Profile"
    doc.body.append(title);
    doc.body.append(style);
    doc.body.append(table);
    win.print();    
}
```

Comment: Now I get this Error: ``Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'append' on 'Document': Only one element on document allowed.``

Comment: Try adding .body to doc.  or use first example